# Как правильно написать, когда речь о многих магазинах?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать предложение:

"«Линзы Хойя Рус» будет доставлять линзы Seiko и Starvision в салоны оптики"
или
"«Линзы Хойя Рус» будет доставлять линзы Seiko и Starvision в салоны оптик"

Answer (score 1):

В салоны оптики (под оптикой будут подразумеваться товары этих заведений, а не они сами, но суть от этого не меняется)

А лучше сказать - в магазины оптики. "В салоны оптик" вариант абсолютно неверный.

И не просто "Линзы...", а компания/организация такая-то будет доставлять линзы такие-то. Лучше название организации тоже в оригинале дать, как виды линз. Потому что это "Хойя Рус" выглядит ужасно.